# Geometric algebra and quantum field theory

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

What does the reformulation of QFT with GA look like?

I read that GA can be applied to almost every kind of physics, but QFT is rarely mentioned.

Is there a lot of research going on in this direction or what is the current state?

Where can I find some literature about it?

Comment: I don't know about "a lot" but Fauser's thesis has a chapter on applying Clifford algebra to QFT, and a long bibliography http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0202059v1.pdf.